# Push object inside a object javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6

Having a object :

```
let test :{ }
```

and dynamically generating objects with my code :

```
const obj =  {
      "ip": {
      "map": {
        "ip": "123",
         "source": "test",
      },
      "op": {
        "unique": "yes"
      }
    },
 }
```

i want to push this dynamically generated object to the inital test object so that , finally the obj looks something like this :

```
 test :{
      "ip": {
      "map": {
        "ip": "123",
         "source": "test",
      },
      "op": {
        "unique": "yes"
      }
    },
  "ip1": {
      "map": {
        "ip": "123",
         "source": "test",
      },
      "op": {
        "unique": "yes"
      }
    },
  "ip2": {
      "map": {
        "ip": "123",
         "source": "test",
      },
      "op": {
        "unique": "yes"
      }
    },
 }
```

Comment: `test = {...obj, ...test}`

Comment: Why not use an array instead?

Comment: `let test :{ }` is not valid JS.

Comment: Why the `"ip"` and than suddenly `"ip1"` 2, 3, 4 etc? Why not use an array instead?

Comment: the desired structure is like that all object of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each assignment i.e. after dynamically generating `obj`, use the spread operator as below :

```
test = {...test, ...obj}
```

the keys `"ip","ip1" ....` must be unique every time you generate `obj` in order to have the desired result.